# access to children of ng-template

Tags: angular, primeng

I am using primeng data table with direct edit, I need to access to children of ng-templateng

There is a table creation:

```
<p-treeTable [value]="files" [columns]="cols">
    <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
        <tr>
            <th *ngFor="let col of columns">
                {{col.header}}
            </th>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowNode let-rowData="rowData" let-columns="columns">
        <tr>
            <td *ngFor="let col of columns; let i = index" ttEditableColumn [ngClass]="{'ui-toggler-column': i === 0}">
                <p-treeTableToggler [rowNode]="rowNode" *ngIf="i === 0"></p-treeTableToggler>
                <p-treeTableCellEditor>
                    <ng-template #test pTemplate="input">
                        <!-- GET THIS TAG -->
                        <input pInputText type="text" [(ngModel)]="rowData[col.field]" [ngStyle]="{'width': i == 0 ? '90%': '100%'}">
                    </ng-template>
                    <ng-template pTemplate="output">{{rowData[col.field]}}</ng-template>
                </p-treeTableCellEditor>
            </td>
        </tr>            
    </ng-template>
</p-treeTable>
```

In my component I use @ViewChildren decorator to grab elements from the host view:

```
 @ViewChildren('test') test: QueryList<TemplateRef<any>>;

 ngAfterViewInit() {
    // console.log(this.test);
    this.test.changes.subscribe(() => {
      this.test.toArray().forEach(el => {

          console.log( el);
      });
    });
  }
```

console output:

```
ElementRef {nativeElement: comment}
    nativeElement: comment
    baseURI: "http://localhost:4200/"
    childNodes: NodeList(0)
    length: 0
    __proto__: NodeList
    data: "bindings={↵  "ng-reflect-name": "input"↵}"
    firstChild: null
    isConnected: false
    lastChild: null
    length: 41
    nextElementSibling: null
    nextSibling: null
    nodeName: "#comment"
    nodeType: 8
    nodeValue: "bindings={↵  "ng-reflect-name": "input"↵}"
    ownerDocument: document
    parentElement: null
    parentNode: null
    previousElementSibling: null
    previousSibling: null
    textContent: "bindings={↵  "ng-reflect-name": "input"↵}"
    __proto__: Comment
    __proto__: Object
```

What do I do wrong? how to get that input inside ng-template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get access to `input`, try to set hash sign `test` to `input`, not to `ng-template`:

```
<ng-template  pTemplate="input">         
     <input 
       #test 
       pInputText type="text" 
       [(ngModel)]="rowData[col.field]" [ngStyle]="{'width': i == 0 ? '90%': '100%'}">
     </ng-template>
</ng-template>
```

TypeScript:

```
@ViewChildren('test') test: any;
```

UPDATE:

You can validate like that:

```
   <input 
       #test 
       pInputText type="text" 
       [(ngModel)]="rowData[col.field]" [ngStyle]="{'width': i == 0 ? '90%': '100%'}">
   <span *ngIf=“rowData[col.field] == 1”> number is incorrect </span>
```

Comment: I tried that,  ngAfterViewInit() returns empty QueryList. Only when input enters direct edit mode I getting only selected element

Comment: @MariaFinkelstein however, this is expected behavior as there is no input element until you start editing cell. There is no ‘input’ element in DOM until you start editing cell. So it is null.

Comment: Makes perfect sense! I am looking away to validate  the data in the column filed when the table is loaded

Comment: @MariaFinkelstein in case of you want to be input must filled in, you can use ‘required’ attribute. In addition, you can set ‘type=“number”’ to input only numbers.

Comment: @MariaFinkelstein  please, see my updated answer about how you can validate your input.

Comment: @ StepUp Thank you very much for helping but that not the problem I have. There is a link for another question I posted with StackBlitz demo.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57190311/primeng-table-validation